# Prepending values into script depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a script that sets up a carousel, however I want to have multiple sizing options for different media types. I was thinking about adding different values into the initializing script with the `jQuery(window).resize(function()` function. However my experiment is just putting the content in as html into the div:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        jQuery('#carousel1')Carousel.prepend('xPos: 500, yRadius: 70');          
});
```

So that puts `xPos: 500` and `yRadius: 70` into the `carousel1` div.

Is it possible to add the conditions to the script, and is this the best way of doing this? I was thinking there might be a way to identify which media query is used and add values dependent on that.

Comment: It really depends on the entire carousel you're using. Can you set it up in a jsfiddle? Also, resizing like this should be handled primarily in CSS media queries, and using jQuery should be a last resort in formatting. There's probably a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by media types? - different browsers/screen-widths/devices/orientations?